# Let $z,w\in\mathbb{C}$ Prove |$z-w|^2\leq(1+|z|^2)(1+|w|^2)$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

I have tried to use $|z|^2=z\bar{z}$ and expand both expressions but I can't complete the demo. I would appreciate any suggestion or help. Thank you 
$$|z-w|^2\leq(1+|z|^2)(1+|w|^2)$$
Edit: Thank you very much for the answers and/or suggestions. It would then look like this: 
Using triangular inequality, you have to $$|z-w|^2\leq(|z|+|w|)^2=|z|^2+|w|^2+2|z||w|$$ 
Also as $$0\leq(1-|z||w|)^2=1-2|z||w|+|z|^2|w|^2$$
then $$2|z||w|\leq1+|z|^2|w|^2$$
Therefore \begin{align*}
|z-w|^2\leq|z|^2+|w|^2+2|z||w|&\leq|z|^2+|w|^2+1+|z|^2|w|^2\\
&=1+|w|^2+|z|^2+|z|^2|w|^2\\
&=(1+|w|^2)+|z|^2(1+|w|^2)\\
&=(1+|z|^2)(1+|w|^2)
\end{align*}

Comment: Just use $(a+b)^2 = a^2+2ab+b^2$ and the triangle inequality.

Comment: Using the triangle inequality gives us a different bound for $|z - w|^2.$ Maybe give that a shot and see where that can get you?

Comment: @StephenDonovan Thanks for answering. Sorry if I'm confused, I'm using this triangle inequality $|z|-|w|\leq|z-w|$ hence I squared and expanded both expressions to $-z\bar{w}-w\bar{z }\leq-2|z||w|$

Comment: @Lumiel Good, I think you've properly applied the property, but you seem to be getting a bit of tunnel vision: the triangle inequality gives you the bound $|z - w|^2 \leq (|z| + |w|)^2.$ Now see if you can establish a relationship between that bound and the one in the original problem statement - it seems like a shot in the dark at first but from my working out it actually works out quite nicely

Comment: hint: write this in terms of two vectors in $\mathbb C^2$ and apply Cauchy-Schwarz

Comment: @StephenDonovan Thank you for your suggestions. In the edition of the question I applied what you mentioned.

Comment: @Lumiel Looks right to me, good job

Answer (score 2):

Let’s follow @Stephen Donovan comment. One has

$$|z-w|^2\leq \left(|z|+|w|\right)^2=|z|^2+|w|^2+2|z||w|$$

On the other hand $(1-|z||w|)^2\geq 0$ and this rewrites as

$$2|z||w|\leq 1+|z|^2|w|^2$$

Can you finish ?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I think I've already seen it. Why $(1-|z||(w|)^2\geq0)$?

Comment: @Lumiel Because it is a squared real number.

Comment: @Thomas Of course, sorry I overlooked the square. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> I have tried to use $|z|^2=z\bar{z}$ and expand both expressions

Here is how OP's approach can be made to work.

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
(1+|z|^2)(1+|w|^2) - |z-w|^2 &= (1+z \bar z)(1+w \bar w) - (z-w)(\bar z - \bar w)
\\ &= 1 + \cancel{z\bar z} + \bcancel{w\bar w} + z \bar z w \bar w - \cancel{z\bar z} + z\bar w + \bar z w - \bcancel{w \bar w}
\\ &= (1 + z \bar w)(1 + \bar z w)
\\ &= (1 + z \bar w)(\overline{1 + z \bar w})
\\ &= |1 + z \bar w|^2
\\ &\ge 0
\end{align}
$$